# Notice: Undefined index: image

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am getting this error Notice: Undefined index: image  . i am trying to upload an image to databse  . I cannot figure out whats going on , everything else uploads except the image, not even the image name is uploaded to database

below is code  the size of the file is only 3kb. the

```
echo $max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')); 

echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";

 echo "<pre>". var_dump($_FILES['image']) . "</pre>";
```

the print_r displays as

```
 Array
(
[title] => This is a post
[author] => Me
[keywords] => posting
[image] => url.jpg
[content] => this is a new post 
[submit] => Publish now
)
```

displays as NULL  the vardump

below is actual code.

```
  <html>

<head> 
<title> inserting new posts </title>
</head>

<body>


<form method="post" action="insert_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data/">

<table width="600" align="centre" border"10">

<tr>
<td> <h1> Insert New Post here </h1> </td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td> Post title <td>
<td> <input type="text" name="title" size="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Post Author<td>
<td> <input type="text" name="author" size="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Post keywords<td>
<td> <input type="text" name="keywords" size="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Post image <td>    
<td> <input type="file" name="image"> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td> Post Content <td>
<td> <textarea name="content" cols="20" rows="20" size="30"> </textarea> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Post title <td>
<td> <input type="text" name="title" size="30"> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish now"> </td>
</tr>

</table>

</form> 



</body>
</html>


<?php


include('../includes/connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


echo $post_title=$_POST['title'];

echo $post_date=date('d-m-y');

echo $post_author=$_POST['author'];

echo $post_keywords=$_POST['keywords'];

echo $post_content=$_POST['content'];

echo $post_image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

echo $image_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];




if($post_title=='' or $post_keywords=='' or $post_content=='' or $post_author==''){

echo "<script> alert('none of the fields can be empty')</script>";

exit();

}  else{

move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/$post_image");

    //query is below to insert data 

$insert_query="INSERT into posts
(post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_keywords,post_content)
 VALUES('$post_title','$post_date','$post_author','$post_image','$post_keywords','$post_content')";



if(mysqli_query($connect,$insert_query)){

echo " <h1> successfully Posted </h1> ";


} else " h1> Did not work </h1>";




}








} 


 echo $max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')); 

echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";

 echo "<pre>". var_dump($_FILES['image']) . "</pre>";
```

?>

Comment: you have a typo in the form `enctype="multipart/form-data/` should be `enctype="multipart/form-data`

Comment: You print `$_POST` but use `var_dump($_FILES)`. Please note that you're open to SQL injection and the upload of PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in `enctype` syntax :

```
<form method="post" action="insert_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data/">
```

This should be

```
<form method="post" action="insert_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

More [information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)